# Not writing the int value. Please correct the program

Tags: java

please correct the program.

> Q. Write a java prg to accept RollNo, Name of a Student and store it in
>   Student.txt.Accept n records and store it.

Following are the drawbacks of o/p produced
1. When we write rno i.e. int {roll no of stud} to the file "Student.txt" it does
not write the int value

i/p

```
C:\j2sdk1.4.1_01\bin>java StudentInfo
Enter how many students
3
Student 1
Enter Roll no.:
1
Enter Name :
Geeta
Student 2
Enter Roll no.:
2
Enter Name :
Pinky
Student 3
Enter Roll no.:
3
Enter Name :
Shaily
```

o/p written to file "student.txt" is
GeetaPinkyShaily

2) When we print the values in Student.txt then student roll no is displayed correctly
loop used is

```
while((b=fin.read())!=-1)
{
 System.out.print(b);
}
```

But as `char c=(char) b;`
is not done it does not print the name

```
C:\j2sdk1.4.1_01\bin>java StudentInfo
Enter how many students
3
Student 1
Enter Roll no.:
1
Enter Name :
Geeta
Geeta
Student 2
Enter Roll no.:
2
Enter Name :
Pinky
Pinky
Student 3
Enter Roll no.:
3
Enter Name :
Shaily
Shaily
Contents of "Student.txt" are :
1711011011169728010511010712138310497105108121
C:\j2sdk1.4.1_01\bin>


                              or
```

vice versa

```
while((b=fin.read())!=-1)
{
 char ch=(char) b;
 System.out.print(ch);
}
```

prints the the names correctly but not roll no

Following is the code. Kindly make the necessary changes.

```
import java.io.*;
class StudentInfo
{
 int rno;
 String name;
 StudentInfo()
 {
  rno=0;
  name="";
 }
 void getDetails() throws IOException
 {
  BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  System.out.println("Enter Roll no.: ");
  rno=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
  System.out.println("Enter Name : ");
  name=br.readLine();
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
 {
  FileOutputStream fout=null;
  FileInputStream fin;
  int n;
  char space=' ';
  try
  {
   //open Student.txt
   try
   {
    fout=new FileOutputStream("Student.txt");
   }
   catch(FileNotFoundException e)
   {
    System.out.println("Error opening the file Student.txt");
    System.exit(0);
   }
   BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
   System.out.println("Enter how many students");
   n=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
   StudentInfo s[]=new StudentInfo[n];
   for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
    s[i]=new StudentInfo();
    System.out.println("Student "+(i+1));
    s[i].getDetails();
    int rollno=s[i].rno;
    fout.write(rollno);
    char c[]=s[i].name.toCharArray();
    for(int z=0;z<c.length;z++)
    fout.write(c[z]);
   }
   fout.close();
   System.out.println("Contents of \"Student.txt\" are : ");
   fin=new FileInputStream("Student.txt");
   int b;
   while((b=fin.read())!=-1)
   {
    System.out.print(b);
   }
   fin.close();
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
   System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  }
 }
}
```

I guess if we can distinguish between the roll no and name we can solve this.
In the o/p file I want o/p as 
rno name rno name rno name
i.e.
1 Geeta 2 Pinky 3 Shaily

Then, how to insert it ?

if I declare as

```
char ch=' ';
fout.write(ch);
```

it writes 32

And even if

```
char ch=' ';
fout.write((int)ch);
```

it wites 32 to Student.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use an `OutputStream` directly to write text data. Use a `Writer` of some form, so you can write strings out instead.

The absolute *simplest* approach would be to open a `PrintWriter`, but that masks errors. The next level up is to use a `FileWriter`, but that will always use the system default encoding. It may be good enough for your purposes.

Converting numbers into text is normally a culture-dependent process, but again I'll ignore that for the moment for the sake of simplicity. So, using `FileWriter` wrapped in a `BufferedWriter` (to make it easier to write a new line):

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Student.txt"));
try
{
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        s[i]=new StudentInfo();
        System.out.println("Student "+(i+1));
        s[i].getDetails();
        writer.write(s[i].rno + ": " + s[i].name);
        writer.newline();
    }
}
finally
{
    writer.close(); // Close output even if there's an error
}
```

There are various other aspects of the code which aren't ideal, but this should at least help with the file format...

Answer (score 1):

You could use DataOutputStream here. FileOutputStream can write everything as bytes only.Please refer this
[Sun API Reference](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html)

In this you could use [writeInt](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeInt(int)) for RollNumber and [writeChars](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeChars(java.lang.String)) for Name. It will be also better if you write each record in a separate line inside the file just for better understanding :)

Answer (score 1):

If you ask the community to correct your programs you will only get downvotes. Instead highlight your specific question. In this case it is why does

```
char ch=' ';
fout.write(ch);
```

Outputs 32. Think about it..why does `System.out.print` the right thing but not `fout.write`? What is the difference between `fout` and `System.out`, if any? What is difference between `write` and `print`, if any? Look up the documentation.

Best of luck with your homework, at least you didn't pretend that it is not.